# numpy unique always the same?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using the following code snippet to get a list of unique arrays, but it reorders the list in a strange way. Is `uniquecoords` bound to be in the same order every time or is there any random factor?

```
for c in coordiantes:
    coords.extend(c)
a = np.array(coords)
uniquecoords = np.unique(
    a.view(
        np.dtype( (np.void, a.dtype.itemsize*a.shape[1]) ))
    ).view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, a.shape[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc of `numpy.unique()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), the function "Returns the sorted unique elements of an array.". So the order should always be the same.

If you want to keep the original order, you can do

```
_, idx = np.unique(your_array_of_views, return_index=True)

uniquecoords = a[idx]
```